# Will this memory fit into my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I'm planning to upgrade my MacBook Pro with another 4GB memory.
How do I know which memory is compatible with my MacBook?

I got MacBook Pro model A1278, processor 2.3 GHZ Intel Core i5, current memory 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3. Would [this memory](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Mac%E7%94%A8%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AAiMac-MacBookPro%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C204Pin-PC3-8500-1066MHz%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9CS-O-DIMM-4GB%C3%972-%E8%A8%888GB/dp/B00CLLS7IS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1411631305&sr=8-1&keywords=mac%20%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA%204gb) fit into my hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have here two helpful Links for you:

[Apple Support Serial Number](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) &
[Apple Support Memory Upgrade](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4132)

I don't have experience with this memory, but i *think* it should work ;) But please use the provided Links and double check everything. I don't know how it is in Jp but in Europe you can send the RAM back to Amazon if it does not work. "Normally" a wrong RAM is not warming you Macbook.

I hope this will help you and sorry if we can't provide for every RAM Module Experience ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's really educative. According to the page, it seems that I need a memory with "PC3-10600 DDR3 1333" for my MacBook Pro, early 2011. Gotta look for another memory with the same spec just to be sure!

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have invalid data. There is no A1287 MBP model. There are A1286, A1297, A1278 and A1286. Would you please clarify? I would be happy to help with the correct information. (There are others, but those are the closest IDs to what you wrote.)

MacBook Pro A1278 configurations are as follows:

13" Mid-2009 Max 8 GB RAM PC3-8500 1066 MHz MacBookPro5,5

13" Mid-2010 Max 16 GB RAM PC3-8500 1066 MHz MacBookPro7,1

13" Early-2011 Max 16 GB RAM PC-10600 1333 MHz MacBookPro8,1

13" Late-2011 Max 16 GB RAM PC-10600 1333 MHz MacBookPro8,1

13" Mid-2012 Max 16 GB RM PC3-12800 1600 MHz MacBookPro9,2

You can use the System Information app in Applications | Utilities to determine which of the MacBookPro models you have. From there, it should be easy for you to determine compatible memory.

This information was all gleaned from Mactracker, a free download from the App Store.

Comment: Spot on, I mistyped. Please check the updated question!

Answer (score 1):

Crucial is a trusted and renowned company which sells memory sticks and SSD drives at affordable prices. On their [front page](http://www.crucial.com/) you can use the Crucial Advisor Tool, if you know the system specs, or download the Crucial System Scanner, which will scan your system for compatible upgrades.

They guarantee 100% compatibility on either tool.

> Using either tool guarantees compatibility when you order on Crucial.com

[image: Crucial Snapshot]

**Disclaimer**: I ordered from them in the past and I can recommend their service as a customer, but you can just use the tools and order from a third party.